# What are the tax rates for an Ireland-based ltd for invoices to company in foreign countries

Tags: foreign-income, italy, ireland

I'm currently working as an IT consultant in Italy (self-employed) but I'm thinking of moving to Ireland next year and open a ltd company there.

I was trying to understand the tax rates and as per my understanding there is a fixed corporate tax of 12.5% for '*trading income with “substance” in Ireland*' (cit.) and 25% for all other cases.

Now that's the part I don't understand, what does it mean to have trading income with substance in Ireland?

I'll plan to move there, find an apartment and find local clients. I think the tax rate for those new clients will be 12.5%, right?

My doubt is about the tax rate for old clients in Italy. Of course I don't want to lose them so I'll still work for them in remote and send them an invoice from my ltd. Will those "foreign" income be taxed at 12.5% or 25%?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link suggests](http://taxsummaries.pwc.com/ID/Ireland-Corporate-Taxes-on-corporate-income) the different rates are for:

- 12.5% : normal income.
- 25% : passive income (e.g. dividends, royalties, etc.)

So both your Irish and Italian client income should be taxed at 12.5%, unless you are charging royalties as part of your service.

Comment: Finally a place that gets it right.  Incentivize productivity.